# How do I access environment variables in an OpenFL project xml file

Tags: compilation, environment-variables, haxe, openfl

In an OpenFL `project.xml` file, how do you access environment variables, for example, to add a source path of `$HOME/dev/haxe-js-kit`

There's lots of information on the [project XML format](http://www.openfl.org/learn/resources/command-line-tools/project-files/xml-format/) from the OpenFL website, but it doesn't mention the above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the variable name in `${}`, e.g.

```
<source path="${HOME}/dev/haxe-js-kit" />
```

Comment: Also works for values set using `<set name="var" value="val" />` and then e.g. `<assets path="Assets/${var}" rename="assets" />`